# Problem in reading flutter Map() data that is saved on Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[Showing database firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgmjU.png)

Hi,
I am trying to display Map() data that is saved in firestore with the below code.

```dart
 snapshot.data.data['MyMobile'].forEach((key,value)=> Text("$key $value"))
```

It is showing below error

```
I/flutter (23045): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (23045): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty,
I/flutter (23045): dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot,
I/flutter (23045): AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>>#46607):
I/flutter (23045): The method 'forEach' was called on null.
I/flutter (23045): Receiver: null
I/flutter (23045): Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => Text)
```

Comment: Try fetching the document and then use .data().map['[FIELD_NAME]'] to get the each map field.

Comment: I need to get the keys and values in list form like
Mobile : Status
Phone 1 : Status 1
Phone 2 : Status 2

I am new to flutter and not getting any workable solution to this problem.
By now I am able to get MAP data on screen but it the complete data like {key1:value1, key2:value2...}
but I am failed to get this data as individual items like list tile.

Comment: Check the 'Decoding with json' part in this link https://codingwithjoe.com/dart-fundamentals-working-with-json-in-dart-and-flutter/